# COPY INTO snowflake table not loading data even with Force command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working on loading data from s3 bucket to snowflake table & using the copy into command.

```
COPY INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLE
FROM s3://test1/test.tsv
STORAGE_INTEGRATION = "TEST_S3"
FILE_FORMAT = (type = "CSV" field_delimiter = ' ' skip_header = 0)
ON_ERROR = "CONTINUE"
;
```

First time it run successfully & data was loaded. when tried to re-run the copy command it failed to load data & returned - **Copy executed with 0 files processed.**

Then checked the documentation & understood that I should FORCE=TRUE but still gets the same message - **Copy executed with 0 files processed.**

```
COPY INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLE
FROM s3://test1/test.tsv
STORAGE_INTEGRATION = "TEST_S3"
FILE_FORMAT = (type = "CSV" field_delimiter = ' ' skip_header = 0)
ON_ERROR = "CONTINUE"
FORCE = TRUE
;
```

Couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong. Does any one have any idea?

Comment: Check the view `snowflake.account_usage.copy_history` and see if there were any errors?

Comment: @SimonD, yeah the copy history doesn't records it here as the re run statement isn't technically copying data.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I got it now.

Both the above codes delete the copied file in external storage & doesn't allow us to re copy with file being not present.

So if you don't wanna delete file after being copied, add the command PURGE=FALSE & re running the copy into command(with FORCE=TRUE) works & duplicates the record.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be ON_ERROR = CONTINUE (without quotes). Perhaps that is stopping Snowflake from reading the FORCE option?